# How to use proper variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have variable `$lang` which convert string to the selected language but i am unable to convert the string getting form database

working

```
echo $lang["hello"];
```

not working

```
$rowtxt = $row[0];
echo $lang[$rowtxt];
```

it shows error.

what is the correct way to do this can any one tell me i am a beginner ?.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$row[0]` contains 'hello'?

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: it was a example that $lang["helloo"] is working it conver the "hello" string to the other language and the other case the $row[0] contains another string which is the query result which i want to convert

Comment: Please show your `$row` array and what is error showing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better a try var_dump($row) or print_r($row) first to see if the array contains the datas at right keys.

$lang[$row[0]] doesnt work because $row[0] is empty.

Your are probably not assigning Hello to $row[0].

So try print_r($row); to see whats stored in the whole array.

Add :

$lang[$row[0]] will give you $lang[hello].

It should be $lang["$row[0]"] for it to be $lang["hello"]

Sample code :

```
$row = array("Hello","Hello Again");
$lang['Hello'] = "Working";
echo $lang["$row[0]"];
```

Please change your attitude. Give out codes, and wait for people to answer. People are here to help.

Ask your question and people will answer you, but please dont DEMAND.

Comment: it contains data that data is string and i want to use that sting with $lang

Comment: You should better post more of your code.

Updated my post with some infos.

Comment: result of print_r($row); `(
    [0] => user city
    [1] => user phone
    [2] => user pin 
)`

Comment: the "hello" was the example for you !!! no one can answer i think !

Comment: Yes, because it is a mystery.
Updated the main post.

Answer (score 1):

what is the correct way to do this?

```
echo $lang[$row[0]];
```

if `$row[0]` contains `hello`

Comment: what is the answer in this ???

Comment: What do you mean what is the answer? This is the answer - the code you posted is fine, but clearly the variable $row[0] does not contain the data you think it does.

Comment: $row is a result of a query i means the and $row[0] is an array having string in its 0th index i want to use that string with $lang[0th sting of row ] understand ???

Comment: I don't know how many times this has to be told, but I'll try once more: **$row[0] does not contain what you think it contains.** Try `echo $row[0]`. Does it print `hello`? And *please*, just tell what the error message is already.

Comment: result of   `print_r($row); ( [0] => user city [1] => user phone [2] => user pin )`

Comment: And **what is the error message**?

Comment: using `echo $lang[$row[0]];` does not shows error but it also doesnot print any thing

Comment: When you do `$lang[$row[0]]`, you are effectively doing `$lang["user city"]`, from what you have posted previously `$lang["user city"]` does not exist? Can you post the result of `var_dump($lang)`?